# How to concatenate strings from array in a sed command?

Tags: bash

Here is the sh file in question:

```
dir=$PWD
cplusplus_plotter="$dir"/BlueEdge_Plotter_V7.cpp

array=( "A" "B" "C" "D" )

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    sed -i \
        -e 's/^\([[:blank:]]*char outputFileName_ForBlueEdge\[50\]\).*/\1 = "BlueEdge_Set$i_PeriodRange1.dat;"/i' \
        -e 's/^\([[:blank:]]*char outputFileName_ForPositiveGrowthModels\[50\]\).*/\1 = "PostiveGrowth_Set$i_PeriodRange1.dat;"/i' \
        -e 's!^\([[:blank:]]*char log_directory_prefix\[30\]\).*!\1 = "LOGS_$i/LOGS_$i;"!i' \
        "$cplusplus_plotter"
    g++ -o Set$i_BlueEdge "$cplusplus_plotter"
    ./Set$i_BlueEdge
done
```

If you cannot tell, I am trying to iterate through the array and concatenate the strings in the sed commands with each element. However, instead of the desired output:

```
    char inputFileName[30] = "input.dat"; //File with the model parameters
    char outputFileName_ForBlueEdge[50] = "BlueEdge_SetB_PeriodRange1.dat"; 
    char outputFileName_ForPositiveGrowthModels[50] = "PostiveGrowth_SetB_PeriodRange1.dat"; 
    char log_directory_prefix[30] = "LOGS_B/LOGS_B";
    char LINAFileName[30] = "LINA_period_growth.data"; //Normally should be "LINA_period_growth.data"
```

This happens:

```
    char inputFileName[30] = "input.dat"; //File with the model parameters
    char outputFileName_ForBlueEdge[50] = "BlueEdge_Set$i_PeriodRange1.dat"; 
    char outputFileName_ForPositiveGrowthModels[50] = "PostiveGrowth_Set$i_PeriodRange1.dat"; 
    char log_directory_prefix[30] = "LOGS_$i/LOGS_$i";
    char LINAFileName[30] = "LINA_period_growth.data"; //Normally should be "LINA_period_growth.data"
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Compare `i=string; echo '$i';` and `echo "$i"`

Comment: Variables are not expanded inside single quotes.

Comment: I tried surrounding all $i in double quotes: "$i"

Comment: @Poshi Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Everything that is inside single quotes won't be expanded/processed by the shell. So Any `'......$var.....'` won't be modified and will be processed as a literal.